# Spark plugs won't fire! Mechanic for hire?

Tags: buick, cranks-wont-run, lesabre

I have a 1995 Buick LeSabre the car was running perfect. Went to get a tire put on it and the serpentine belt broke. Replaced the belt and tried to crank the car and wasn't getting fire to the spark plugs. The battery keeps dying. Bought a brand new one and tired cranking the car. Still no fire to the plugs. The battery drained in a matter of hours. Why might I not be getting fire at the plugs?

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if there is 12volts at the dist coil pink wire with key on.

Also those had issues with the crank sensor getting damaged due to the sensor ring on the crankshaft harmonic balancer becoming loose or the balancer itself coming apart, the balancer also drives the belt that came off.

There was an updated balancer for that year model also, so there are 2 designs, be sure to get the right one from the dealer using the car vin code.

You may need to replace the balancer and sensor, do not re use the old sensor even if it looks good.